# Running an ec2 instance from other server provider existing image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed ressources on a scalway server scaleway.com (a frensh servers and cloud provider). This server uses ubuntu as os and runs a python app with many installations and configs.
In scalway, you can run a new server from a  server image you had before installed or already existing. In ec2 too, you can surely launch an aws ec2 instances from an existing AMI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html.
But, is there a way please to launch an ec2 instance with a scalway image. It will save  much time in deployment of the app.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends they share or sell their AMIs. But as I searched on AWS Marketplace console, there  seems no AMI from scaleway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Scaleway/comments/jwha9q/is_there_a_way_to_download_an_image/